# Loss of semantics in CSS class names with media queries

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-markup

I'm wondering if there are best practices or solutions for the following issue:

I'm using the CSS framework Semantic UI, and it has some classes, as Bootstrap does, to define column width such as: "one wide column", "two wide column", "three wide column", and so on. But as the screen size gets smaller, sometimes I want the width of those columns to change, and if I don't change the classes and change the sizes, the classes lose their meaning.

I know I can switch classes using JavaScript and detecting screen size, but are there any other, potentially better, ways to keep the meaning yet change the sizes? Should I just avoid classes like these entirely?

Comment: That's the biggest irony about Semantic UI. The obvious choice, therefore, would be to *not* use Semantic UI.

Comment: One of the reasons why I avoid frameworks altogether, because of their naming conventions. I end up writing my own column code in CSS because it's not difficult to do and it's easy to manage.

Comment: Yeah, I've ultimately decided to take what Semantic has, use it as a base, and then modify it with my own wording and rules in the default theme.